# Java 8 Pattern predicate using Stream - how variable is inferred?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream, predicate

I am reading "Java SE 8 for the Really Impatient" and I see some curious code. It's like this:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".....");
final long count = Stream.of("Cristian","Daniel","Ortiz","Cuellar")
      .filter(pattern.asPredicate())
      .count();
```

I just thought that asPredicate method would be something like

```
public boolean asPredicate(String stringToMatch){
    .....
}
```

But the real implementation is like this

```
public Predicate<String>asPredicate(){
    return s -> matcher(s).find();
}
```

I know that I could use something like this which is perfectly legal:

```
final long count = Stream.of("Cristian","Daniel","Ortiz","Cuellar")
      .filter(a->pattern.matcher(a).find())
      .count();
```

But my question is how the stream passes the String to the Pattern instance? how "*Cristian*","*Daniel*","*Ortiz*","*Cuellar*" each are passed to the method `s -> matcher(s).find()`. I mean how the Strings are somehow passed and become the `s` variable of the asPredicate method.

Comment: You know that you can pass `certainKindOfExpression` to `.filter(…)`, so why is it a mystery that you can call `someMethod()` instead, which contains a `return certainKindOfExpression` and then pass the result of `someMethod()` to `.filter(…)`? That’s not special to lambda expressions. If you understand how passing a lambda expression works in `filter`, as you claim, you should understand how the same lambda expression works with a `return` statement. Of course, whether you call the lambda’s parameter `s` or `a` makes no differences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) interface is a functional interface that defines one abstract method `boolean test(T t)` where `T` in this case is the `String` type, since you're filtering on a `Stream<String>`. In other words, the code is equivalent to:

```
final long count = Stream.of("Cristian","Daniel","Ortiz","Cuellar")
  .filter(new Predicate<String>() {
       public boolean test(String s) {
          return matcher(s).find();
       }
   })
  .count();
```